# Remove only these type of chars Ã¢Â€Â¦Ã¢Â€Â¦ using php preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have tried this, but can't remove this kind of chars (Ã¢Â€Â¦Ã¢Â€Â¦) from my string:

```
 $string= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z [\n\r] ]/', '', $string);
 $string= preg_replace('/\t\s\s+/', '', $string);
 $string= preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","=",$string);
```

it shows me my desired out, but I also want to remove special chars like: Ã¢Â€Â¦Ã¢Â€Â¦

Comment: It looks like you are interpreting UTF-8 text as ANSI. I think you should try `iconv` to convert the text to the right codepage.

Comment: I tried this iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string) but still can't remove can you show me how to do with iconv?

Comment: I don't see where you are removing those chars. [a-zA-Z] does not cover them. Think in the opposite way. Which chars you want to keep? and use preg_match instead. That will leave you just with what you need.

Comment: @lepe I just want to keep line breaks with strings.

Comment: This looks like an encoding problem. Trying to solve this by "removing characters" is the absolutely wrong way to go about it. Learn about encodings, learn how to handle them correct: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @M3Dev: what do you mean by "strings"? Does string means to you [a-zA-Z0-9] ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in an online tester

```
 $string= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\n\r]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Why are you puting pipes `|` in the character class?

Comment: @M42 Leftover from testing other options. Code adjusted.